# Where to put Scudo allocator __scudo_default_options callback?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, dynamic-memory-allocation

From Scudo page:

```
Some parameters of the allocator can be defined on a per-process basis through several ways:

Statically: Define a __scudo_default_options function in the program that returns the options string to be parsed. This function must have the following prototype: extern "C" const char *__scudo_default_options().
Dynamically: Use the environment variable SCUDO_OPTIONS containing the options string to be parsed. Options defined this way override any definition made through __scudo_default_options.
```

Im fairly new to Android, could someone help me understand where to put functions like __scudo_default_options in cpp code, I have MainActivity.cpp and MidiManager.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The function can be located anywhere within the application, as long as it's discoverable by the linker. Putting it in the vicinity of your main compilation unit is probably better.
You want to make sure that the symbol has a public visibility.

You can refer to the example in the tests here:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/scudo/standalone/tests/scudo_unit_test_main.cpp#L23

eg. in MainActivity.cpp, something to the extent of:

```
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) const char *
__scudo_default_options() {
  return "quarantine_size_kb=256:thread_local_quarantine_size_kb=128:"
         "quarantine_max_chunk_size=512";
}
```